# spring getting bean using ApplicationContext.getBean()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to get a bean of a class A that implements Class B,

```
public class AndroidDeviceRule implements DeviceRule {}
```

this is fine

```
return (DeviceRule) context.getBean(myBeanName, DeviceRule.class);
```

But, I would prefer something like

```
return (DeviceRule) context.getBean(mybeanName, Class<? extends DeviceRule>);
```

But I can't..

```
- Syntax error on token ",", ( expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
```

Comment: Why can't you just write (DeviceRule)context.getBean(myBeanName)?

Comment: true, I was only curious why I I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to define the actual `DeviceRule` subtype as a generic type at the method level. You can have this in two flavors:

```
// with an explicit type passed in (as in your example)
<T extends DeviceRule> T getSpringBean(String name, Class<T> type) {
    return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name, type);
}


// with no explicit type; will return whatever the caller expects,
// obviously resulting in a ClassCastException if the cast fails.
<T extends DeviceRule> T getSpringBean(String name) {
    return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend **Autowiring** bean for this

```
@Autowired
DeviceRule deviceRule;
```

Much cleaner approach